# How to permanently change sudo's $PATH variable (Ubuntu 9.x)

Tags: path, sudo

I want add some directory to the $PATH when running sudo, this is a (semi) permanent requirement, not something that needs to be added to the scripts themselves. I notice that Django has managed to do it, (my $PATH when running sudo is "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/django/django-trunk/django/bin") - so how did it do that?

Answer (score 17):

This is the line in the sudoers file that resets:

`Defaults env_reset`

You can work around this by adding `PATH` to `env_keeps` or by adding this line:

`Defaults env_keep = "PATH"`

EDIT: meder, you do not disable env_reset, you simply bypass the path reset

Or you can remove the offending `env_reset` line.

Even better though, you can declare a `secure_path` that will replace `PATH` when sudo is run:

`Defaults secure_path="/bin:/usr/bin"`

That way you can control what specific directories to include in the path.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You can limit access to only the paths needed with the sudoer mechanism instead of opening all of root's access.

Comment: Access the sudoers file via 'sudo visudo'

Answer (score 7):

I think this should work out if you save it in /root/.bashrc:

```
export PATH=/www/foo:$PATH
```

I forget if it's PATH or PYTHONPATH and if it actually matters, this is based on my user's .bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/www/django:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to select an answer so others can know it has been solved :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I added the path to /root/.bashrc, then ran "sudo env | grep PATH" and the added path was not present. Perhaps it works for PYTHONPATH, but not for PATH.

Comment: It didn't work for me too. I asked a new question at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717043/changed-sudo-path-command-continues-not-being-found

Comment: This is a bad solution. The file /etc/sudoers exists to allow you to change the behavior of sudo. Opening the default root path to a folder that potentially should not be in the root path is a HORRIBLE idea. Also it is path, not pythonpath that controls where bash looks for executables.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the variable in /etc/environment, and then use "sudo -i" to run the script (works in ubuntu 10.10).