# changed sudo path, command continues not being found

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, sudo

I added

`export PATH="/home/deltrem/Pedro - Arquivos/play/ps1/linux/pSX:$PATH"`

to

`/root/.bashrc`

, but

`sudo pSX`

echoes

`command not found`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you logging in as root? If so, then you have no need for `sudo`.

If not, then the contents of `/root/.bashrc` won't matter, since the `sudo` command gets its path from the environment in which it's run. In other words, it copies your user-level path. Instead, edit the path in your user's `.bashrc`.

Comment: I'm logged in as deltrem, but need temporary root access.

Comment: That's what the `sudo` command does. However, it doesn't run the `/root/.bashrc` script, or any other scripts in root's home directory.

Basically, the path needs to contain the pSX directory before you run `sudo`. The easiest way to do this is to edit your user's `.bashrc` file, then run `. ~/.bashrc` (or log out and back in).

Comment: Have you tried giving sudo the full path to the pSX executable?

Comment: The full path to pSX (the file) worked. `. ~/.bashrc`, then `sudo pSX` didn't work and `sudo . ~/.bashrc`, then `sudo pSX` didn't work.

Comment: Did you add the `export PATH` line in your post to your user's .bashrc?

Comment: It's best to modify your $PATH in .bash_profile instead of .bashrc.  You don't want to have duplicate entries in $PATH for each level of sub-shells you run.

Answer (score 0):

Is `pSX` a directory, a file, or both (a directory called `pSX` containing a file named `pSX`)?  If it's a directory, you need to enter the actual command name instead. If it's a file (but not a directory) then you need to remove the `/pSX` from the `PATH` variable.

Does `pSX` have the executable bit set? The OS might not know that `pSX` is a command.

Comment: a directory (pSX) containing a file (pSX too) and pSX (the file) has the executable bit set

Answer (score 0):

After spending the past hour banging my head against the wall, I finally figured out how to do this. It has nothing to do with bashrc, profile, or environment. Instead open up **/etc/sudoers** and change **secure_path**.